# Matlab str2func with existing workspace function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

Hopefully I can make this as clear as possible, because I'm rather confused myself. I put together a simple example to facilitate discussion.

```
a = @(c) 1 + c;
fcn = str2func('@(x) x+a(x)');
```

This will return an error since "str2func" does no preserve the workspace variable `a` when `fcn` is invoked. This is highlighted in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html). Is there a work around to this problem?

NOTE: hard coding  `a` into the string is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: Why are you using `str2func` in the first place? It's certainly not necessary in your example.

Comment: @David I'm well aware of that. It's a simple example to showcase the problem/question. Regardless of what I'm trying to do, is there a work around to build functions from existing variables/functions in the workspace?

Comment: Ask the full problem, you're likely to get a better overall solution! Do you mean something like `a{1}=@(x) 1+x` `a{2}=@(x) x.^2`, `f=@(x) x+a{i}(x)`?

Comment: @David I tried to avoid a specific problem, since it's really problem independent. I'll will edit my question with a specific example if that helps.

Comment: Dealing with cell arrays of anonymous functions is not very difficult, hence my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow evaluating a custom function handle in `fcn`, you can pass it as an input argument:

```
a = @(c) 1 + c;
fcn = str2func('@(x,a) x+a(x)');

>> fcn(3,a)
ans =
     7
```

If you want `fcn` to have only one argument, you need to define it in two steps:

```
a = @(c) 1 + c;
tmp = str2func('@(x,a) x+a(x)');
fcn = @(x)tmp(x,a);
```